# Allow <body> Styling in HTMLPurifier

Tags: htmlpurifier

I want to allow `<style>` tags in the `<body>` that reference the `body` like:

```
<style>
    body{
        background-color:pink
    }
</style>
```

`Filter.ExtractStyleBlocks` can be used to throw `<style>` into `<head>`, but styles on `body` get removed.

The ideal answer simply adds `body` to the existing list of allowed CSS selectors, rather than requiring a complete list of allowed CSS selectors. Or, the ideal answer may explain why this request is impossible.

Comment: HTML Purifier is (currently) designed for HTML fragments - pieces of HTML that can be placed anywhere within the element declared as HTML.Parent (defaults to 'div'), not full HTML documents. So it doesn't know 'html', 'head', or 'body' elements and simply strips them as it would any other supposedly-invalid tag. Presumably, that's what you're running into here: It doesn't know 'body', so the CSS can't, from its perspective, be valid. Maybe take a look at http://htmlpurifier.org/phorum/read.php?3,6909,6909 for pointers?